# In Excel need to copy a range of cells based on single criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to copy/insert a range of cells based on a single criteria. I have tried using the `IF` function as follows

```
=IF(B6="RHH1",Sheet2!A4:J15,Sheet2!A18)
```

The `FALSE` statement works and the single cell is copied, but the `TRUE` statement fails with a `#Value` error.

I am guessing a macro would work, but not sure on even where to start there.

Comment: The true statement fails because you're trying to set a single cell's value to multiple cells' values.

Comment: This is only an example.

In Sheet1 hi-light cells C7 thru K18

Then click in the formula bar and enter the array formula:

=IF(B6="Ryde",Sheet2!A4:J15,Sheet2!A18)
Array formulas must be entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter rather than just the Enter key.

You can pick another block in Sheet1, but it must be the same "shape" as the block in Sheet2!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent that's a better answer than the two below.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested to achieve this without using Macro, then you need to enter your range value as an Array formula. In order to enter as an array formula,

1. Select the destination range as the same size as the source range
2. Enter the formula
3. Press Control + Shift + Enter

Refer the Microsoft Documentation [Introducing array formulas in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the function (and any function) is just trying to set that single cell (which is why it starts with =) to a value. It doesn't have control of any of the cells around it.

A macro would work, Here is a good starting point to learning about macros. http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/save-time-by-creating-and-running-macros-in-excel-2010-RZ102337714.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Solution in two steps:

1. Enter the following in top-left cell of desired output range:

   > =IF($B$6="RHH1",Sheet2!A4,"")

   Fill this down 11 more rows and then over 9 more columns.
2. Go back to the top-left cell (the first one you entered the formula into) and change its formula to the following:

   > =IF($B$6="RHH1",Sheet2!A4,Sheet2!A18)

This should do the trick.